# Load multiple entities with entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: 7, entities

It's very easy to load entities with `entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid)` - but is there any way to load multiple entities, similar to `node_load_multiple()`?

I've tried passing in an array instead of a single id, but it gives the error: *Invalid data value given*.

If there isn't a function for this, is there an efficient way of doing this, or is a looping the only way?

Comment: Are you sure you can pass the node ID to `entity_metadata_wrapper()`, as your code shows?

Comment: @kiam Definitely, arg 2 is: _The entity to wrap or its identifier_ per http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entity%21includes%21entity.wrapper.inc/function/EntityDrupalWrapper%3A%3A__construct/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't, but you can just combine the two to get the same effect:

```
foreach (node_load_multiple($nids) as $node) {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
}
```

Comment: Well there's no need to load the node, as entity_metadata_wrapper also accepts $nids itself.

Comment: Yep, which it then runs straight through `entity_load`, which in turn does the same thing as running it through `node_load`. Accepting the ID is just a convenience of the function, the node will still be loaded using core API functions, there's no way to get around that. That's why you're asking, right? Because you don't want to run `node_load` in a loop, you want to use functionality synonymous with `node_load_multiple`? EMWs don't have that built in, you need a bit of glue code like the above

Comment: wouldn't `$wrapper` need to be an array and that second line should just pop the emw return value to the wrapper array?

Comment: @cdmo I think the idea here is that you're doing something with the $wrapper in each iteration. You could certainly build a $wrappers array for later use instead if that's what you're looking for.